# When not to use Azure Cosmos DB Bulk Executor?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Should I consider using a bulk executor in Azure Cosmos DB to update/insert 5-10 documents or I'm better off with a loop which inserts documents one-by-one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bulk operations are optimized for large number of documents. For such a low volume, you can simply call them concurrently.

You don't specify which language you are working on, but on C#, you could simply create these 5-10 documents as Tasks in a List and await them all:

```
List<Task> operations = new List<Task>();
foreach(MyDocument document in documents)
{
    operations.Add(client.CreateDocumentAsync(....));
}

await Task.WhenAll();
```

For the V3 .NET SDK we have a blog that talks about Bulk and what is not Bulk: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/